# Item length in function of other items

Tags: wpf

**What I want to achieve**

I would like to create specific control to be able to display a header and some elements link to the header :

- A column with the number of the comment, fixed size
- A column with a name (Currently COMMENT): unfixed size
- A column with a name (currently GRAPH XT) : fixed size
- A column with a name (currently Time) : fixed size
- A column with a name (currently Visible) : fixed size

The user can resize the environment and only the second column must adapt. As you can see in the gif below :

[via GIPHY](https://giphy.com/gifs/lqavQ6LGsmSzmRzG4g)

(The gif was created by setting all the columDefinition width to a fixed size)

**The problem**

All the columns must be aligned with the other item (as in the gif). The size of each column must be exactly the same and are determined by the item with the bigger content. In the image below, you can see the problem I'm facing. The content is not aligned and I can't size the column.
[image]

**What I currently have**

I try to design with the MVVM spirit

I use an ItemsControl to display data over the biding of ItemsSource. To modify the template of the data, I'm using the DataTemplate.
But now, I would like to access the grid of each item (which is in "CommentsListItemControl") to measure their column length and finally apply the biggest length to all the column.

I override the "load" event of the CommentsListItemControl, but I'm not able to get the parent to have all the CommentsListItemControl items.
I then override the "load" event of the ItemsControl of the CommentsListControl but i'm not able to get their container (and then check all the children).
I was using this resource to help me : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-find-datatemplate-generated-elements

```
var items = (ItemsControl)grid.Children[0];
            items.ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged += (sss,eee) => {
                var it = items.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(items.Items[0]);
                // Here I check if it was an item i was looking for but no
                ;
            } ;
```

And the code i come up above (not working)

**Question**

How can I get the grid "" via the ItemsControl ? I'm searching for more than 10 hours now...
Is my explanation enough clear and complete ?

**Code below**

```
<UserControl x:Class="CCTT.CommentsListControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CCTT"
         xmlns:design ="clr-namespace:CCTT.ViewModels"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">

<Grid DataContext="{x:Static design:CommentsListDesignModel.Instance}" >
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate >
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:CommentsListItemControl />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

```
<UserControl x:Class="CCTT.CommentsListItemControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CCTT"
         xmlns:design ="clr-namespace:CCTT.ViewModels"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="600">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:ListItemTypeToVisibilityValueConverter x:Key="ListItemTypeToVisibilityValueConverter"/>
    <local:TimeToStringValueConverter x:Key="TimeToStringValueConverter"/>
</UserControl.Resources>


<Grid d:DataContext="{x:Static design:CommentsListItemDesignModel.Header}" Background="AliceBlue" VerticalAlignment="Center" >

    <!-- Header -->
    <Grid Visibility="{Binding ItemType, Converter={StaticResource ListItemTypeToVisibilityValueConverter}, ConverterParameter=Header}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <!-- Number of comment -->
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <!-- Comment -->
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <!-- Graph name -->
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <!-- Time -->
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <!-- Visibility -->
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <!-- Number of comment -->
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="#"  Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <!-- Comment -->
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Comment}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="30,10"/>
        <!-- Graph name -->
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding GraphName}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Margin="10"/>
        <!-- Time -->
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding TimeText}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,10"/>
        <!-- Visibility -->
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Text="{Binding VisibilityText}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="30,10"/>
    </Grid>

    <!-- Item -->
    <Grid Visibility="{Binding ItemType, Converter={StaticResource ListItemTypeToVisibilityValueConverter}, ConverterParameter=Normal}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <!-- Number of comment -->
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <!-- Comment -->
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <!-- Graph name -->
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <!-- Time -->
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <!-- Visibility -->
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <!-- Number of comment -->
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Index}"  Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <!-- Comment -->
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Comment}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="30,10"/>
        <!-- Graph name -->
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding GraphName}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10"/>
        <!-- Time -->
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding Time, Converter={StaticResource TimeToStringValueConverter}, ConverterParameter=d/MM/yyyy HH:mm}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,10"/>
        <!-- Visibility -->
        <CheckBox Grid.Column="4" IsChecked="{Binding IsVisible}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="30,10"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after closing/opening VS it begins to work ...

Here is the real code if someone need it :

**Interaction logic**

```
/// <summary>
    /// Take care of displaying correctly a list of <see cref="CommentsListItemControl"/> by changing their size if needed
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">And ItemsControl</param>
    /// <param name="e"> A routed event</param>
    private void ItemsControl_Loaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Get the maximum grid colum size.
        List<double> maxSizeColumn = GetGridColumnSize(sender as ItemsControl, "Main_CommentsListItemControl_DO_NOT_CHANGE");
        if (maxSizeColumn == null)
            return;

        //initialize the list
        List<GridLength> gridLengths = new List<GridLength>(new GridLength[maxSizeColumn.Count]);

        for (int i = 0; i < maxSizeColumn.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i == 1)
                // Let the user be able to resize the content
                gridLengths[i] = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);

            gridLengths[i] = new GridLength(maxSizeColumn[i]);

        }

        SetColumSize(sender as ItemsControl, "Main_CommentsListItemControl_DO_NOT_CHANGE", gridLengths);

    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Search all the column width for the specific control <see cref="CommentsListItemControl"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="control">An itemsControl with <see cref="CommentsListItemControl"/>datatemplate</param> 
    /// <param name="containerName">The name of the main container of the <see cref="CommentsListItemControl"/></param>
    /// <returns>The maximum width of all columnDefinition inside the control</returns>
    private List<double> GetGridColumnSize(ItemsControl control, string containerName)
    {
        if (control == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(control));

        List<double> gridSize = null;

        // Check the width for each item inside de control
        for (int i = 0; i < control.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            // get the container
            var itemControlItem = control.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
            if (itemControlItem == null)
                // if the container is not already loaded, return
                return null;

            // get the main grid

            Grid mainGrid = UIHelpers.FindChild<Grid>(itemControlItem, containerName);

            //Get the child grid only if visible
            var childrenGrid = (((Grid)mainGrid.Children[0]).Visibility == Visibility.Visible) ? (Grid)mainGrid.Children[0] : (Grid)mainGrid.Children[1];

            //initialize the list
            if (gridSize == null)
                gridSize = new List<double>(new double[childrenGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Count]);

            //Get the size of every column
            for (int j = 0; j < childrenGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Count; j++)
            {
                // find the size of the grid and if bigger than the previous one, record it
                gridSize[j] = Math.Max(gridSize[j], childrenGrid.ColumnDefinitions[j].ActualWidth);
            }
        }

        return gridSize;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Set the column width of a <see cref="ItemsControl"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="control">The control where the column width must be applied</param>
    /// <param name="containerName">The name of the main container of the <see cref="CommentsListItemControl"/></param>
    /// <param name="gridLengths">The <see cref="GridLength"/> to be set</param>
    private void SetColumSize(ItemsControl control, string containerName, List<GridLength> gridLengths)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < control.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            // get the container
            var itemControlItem = control.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
            if (itemControlItem == null)
            {
                // if the container is not found, inform the user and return
                Debugger.Break();
                return;
            }

            // get the main grid
            Grid mainGrid = UIHelpers.FindChild<Grid>(itemControlItem, containerName);

            //Get the child grid only if visible
            var childrenGrid = (((Grid)mainGrid.Children[0]).Visibility == Visibility.Visible) ? (Grid)mainGrid.Children[0] : (Grid)mainGrid.Children[1];

            //Check if size are consistent
            if (childrenGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Count != gridLengths.Count)
            {
                // do nothing and inform the user
                Debugger.Break();
                return;
            }
            //Apply the size for every column
            for (int j = 0; j < childrenGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Count; j++)
            {
                // find the size of the grid and if bigger than the previous one, record it
                if (j == 1)
                    continue;
                childrenGrid.ColumnDefinitions[j].Width = gridLengths[j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Related XAML**

```
<UserControl x:Class="CCTT.CommentsListControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CCTT"
         xmlns:design ="clr-namespace:CCTT.ViewModels"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">

<Grid DataContext="{x:Static design:CommentsListDesignModel.Instance}" >
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Loaded="ItemsControl_Loaded">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate >
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:CommentsListItemControl />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

**Helper**

```
public static class UIHelpers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Finds a Child of a given item in the visual tree. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parent">A direct parent of the queried item.</param>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the queried item.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="childName">x:Name or Name of child. </param>
    /// <returns>The first parent item that matches the submitted type parameter. 
    /// If not matching item can be found, 
    /// a null parent is being returned.</returns>
    public static T FindChild<T>(DependencyObject parent, string childName)
       where T : DependencyObject
    {
        // Confirm parent and childName are valid. 
        if (parent == null) return null;

        T foundChild = null;

        int childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
        for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
            // If the child is not of the request child type child
            T childType = child as T;
            if (childType == null)
            {
                // recursively drill down the tree
                foundChild = FindChild<T>(child, childName);

                // If the child is found, break so we do not overwrite the found child. 
                if (foundChild != null) break;
            }
            else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(childName))
            {
                var frameworkElement = child as FrameworkElement;
                // If the child's name is set for search
                if (frameworkElement != null && frameworkElement.Name == childName)
                {
                    // if the child's name is of the request name
                    foundChild = (T)child;
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // child element found.
                foundChild = (T)child;
                break;
            }
        }

        return foundChild;
    }
}
```